# How to convert n*1 array into n*m array where m is unique values in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of array( [1,2,3, 4, 1,2 ,3 ,3,3,3]) having shape (10,)

```
a = np.array([1,2,3, 4, 1,2 ,3 ,3,3,3])
print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

which has unique values 1,2,3,4 ie m = 4, unique values.
Actual data i quite large nad has nuniuqe of ~300
How to pivot it to get an array of shape (10,4)

Expected output

```
 array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1,  0],
       [0, 0, 0,  1],
       [1, 0, 0,  0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, `,  0]])
```

Comment: What would the array look like? What have you tried?

Comment: tried a pandas.pivot function , with no index

Comment: What should the output be for `a = np.array([1,3,5,3,1])`?

Comment: @mozway, base on question here `[1,3,5,3,1]` -> `m=3` (we have three unique value(1,3,5)) then shape of output should be like `(5,3)`

Comment: @I'mahdi I felt it could be interpreted in two ways depending on whether `m` is the number of unique or the max number (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497243/16343464)), so I rather asked ;)

Comment: @mozway, I see your answer, I think the first part is OK `(a[:,None] == np.unique(a)).astype(int)`, Because OP exactly say : **`which has unique values`**, But I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using broadcasting comparison:

```
out = (a[:,None] == np.unique(a)).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

##### alternative

If you want to ensure having empty columns on missing numbers:

```
out = (a[:,None] == np.arange(a.max())+1).astype(int)
```

To see the difference, let's use `a = np.array([1,3,5,3,1])` as input:

```
a = np.array([1,3,5,3,1])

array([1, 3, 5, 3, 1])


(a[:,None] == np.unique(a)).astype(int)

#       1  3  5
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])


(a[:,None] == np.arange(a.max())+1).astype(int)

#       1  2  3  4  5
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
np.eye(a.max(),dtype=int)[a - 1]

array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

```
>>> import pandas as pd

# use '.values' for converting result to 'numpy.array'
>>> b = pd.get_dummies(a).values

>>> b.shape
(10, 4)

>>> b
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```